# How to connect python to Azure Cloud and create azure data factory

Tags: python, azure, ssl

Please help me on how to connect to Azure cloud using Python and How can we create ADF using Python.I am getting following error message:
I am getting SSL TLS certificate error

```
pip install azure-mgmt-resource
Collecting azure-mgmt-resource
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_ACCESS_DENIED] tlsv1 alert access denied (_ssl.c:1051)'))': /simple/azure-mgmt-resource/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_ACCESS_DENIED] tlsv1 alert access denied (_ssl.c:1051)'))': /simple/azure-mgmt-resource/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_ACCESS_DENIED] tlsv1 alert access denied (_ssl.c:1051)'))': /simple/azure-mgmt-resource/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_ACCESS_DENIED] tlsv1 alert access denied (_ssl.c:1051)'))': /simple/azure-mgmt-resource/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_ACCESS_DENIED] tlsv1 alert access denied (_ssl.c:1051)'))': /simple/azure-mgmt-resource/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/azure-mgmt-resource/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/azure-mgmt-resource/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_ACCESS_DENIED] tlsv1 alert access denied (_ssl.c:1051)'))) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement azure-mgmt-resource (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for azure-mgmt-resource
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_ACCESS_DENIED] tlsv1 alert access denied (_ssl.c:1051)'))) - skipping
```

Answer (score 0):

@user2524829 - Please follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-python) document for creating ADF using python.

The issue that you are facing might be due to an old version of pip.

Try running the below command first:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a network issue. Either switch to other network or try with proxy configured.